# OCI not able to access public ip

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82TmC.png)

I create a OCI Instance and got a Public IP, I configure the webserver with the allowed ports number. but not able to access web server with ip, when I check with putty able to log in and check with ifconfig but dint finds any public ip.

Comment: FYI this belongs on ServerFault, not Stack Overflow. Also, please read [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

**You Need to allow Traffic through the Firewall...install "firewall-cmd" then**

Run the following command to allow traffic on port 80:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http
```

Run the following command to allow traffic on port 443:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=https
```

Run the following command to save the firewalld rules:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```